# How to add multiple fact tables in a single mondrian cube in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, cube, mondrian, fact

Need to associate multiple fact tables with a mondrian cube. The schema workbench doesn't allow to do so. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add multiple fact tables in a cube. Schema workbench expects you to have a Star schema in which there will just be one fact table.  If you need to combine information from two fact tables on the same subject but with different or same granularity, then you must create a virtual cube. It is easy and very convenient. You can refer to the following documentation:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0N0/020/040/000

Comment: You can get even more help and ideas for virtual cubes here: http://diethardsteiner.github.io/mondrian/2017/03/20/Mondrian-Multivalued-Dimension-Attribute.html.

Note virtual cubes are deprecated in Mondrian4, but that doesnt seem to be seeing the light of day any time soon. (It's replaced with a better way of doing what the OP is after)